# How to Produce a Rectangular Radial Glow

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, tikz-pic, calc, tikz-fadings

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in,vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\definecolor{forestgreen}{rgb}{.13, .55, .13}
\definecolor{sunriseyellow}{RGB}{255,219,0}


% I compile this code with Xelatex
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\centering
\tikzfading[name=fade out, inner color=transparent!0,
outer color=transparent!100]
\tikzset{
  star/.style={forestgreen, fill=sunriseyellow, path fading=fade out}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-1.65, -2.15) rectangle (1.65, 2.15);
     \draw[forestgreen!35!black, shading=mradial, inner color=sunriseyellow!65!white, 
     middle color=forestgreen!60!black, outer color=forestgreen!35!black]
    (-1.65, -2.15) rectangle (1.65, 2.15)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I modify the code in order to get the radial glow to extend over the entire rectangular region? Presently, the code produces a circular-type radial glow. (Actually, a circular radial glow, which in this case, appears egg-shaped because the `tikzpicture` is not a perfect square.)

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that there are no answers because the question is not very clear. For example, would this version of the code work for you?It seems to me that there are no answers because the question is not very clear. For example, would it work if you had a version of this code where the second rectangle is set like this
    `(-1.65*2, -2.15*10) rectangle (1.65*2, 2.15*10);`

Comment: Your suggestion seems to create a *new* rectangle (as opposed to working with the rectangle given as indicated by: "to get the radial glow to extend over **the** entire rectangular region")---which (your rectangle) sort of magnifies the interior of the present glow depending on the dimensions  you use. To rephrase what I had asked:  I want to produce a rectangular radial display instead of the circular-type one currently produced by the MWE.

Comment: Do you want a perfect circular radial glow that goes along the larger side?